# What is this low, leathery serrated leaved plant from the Piedmont region of Maryland?

Tags: identification

I found this plant growing in semi-shade along with the garlic mustard and grape vine. It has five elongated leaflets to each leaf. It is not evergreen, as it came up this spring. At first I thought it was [Mayapple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podophyllum), but then I found some Mayapple further into the woods and this isn't it. Then I thought maybe [ginseng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginseng), but I'm having doubts about that. I'm trying to remove invasive plants from this property, and encourage natives.

Which is this please?

[image]

[<sup>source</sup>](http://naturalwonderlife.com/images/GH_Flora/LowGreenery5PointedLeatheryLeaves.jpg)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think that the plant with 5 fingered leaves smack in the middle is Rodgersia.  When it flowers, you'll be able to tell which species/variety. WONDERFUL perennial!!

Comment: I believe you're right @stormy. It's not native to here, but at least it's not on noxious or invasive lists. Originated in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodgersia)Asia. Thank you.

Comment: Rodgersia's are big plants. I'm not sure this identification is correct. Check for thick rhizomes under the soil and if the habitat is moist.

Comment: You may be right @kevinsky. Nothing on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodgersia) mentions height, but their image appears to show low growing greenery. For now, I'm not going to remove it and hope it blooms for better ID. It grows on the shaded bank at the edge of the woods.

Comment: I used to have a couple...wonderful plant to pop out amongst others. I'd forgotten them and had to look them up.  If it isn't Rodgersia I want to know.  They do well in part shade, good rich soil.

Comment: I don't think it is Rodgersia. Look at the serration. Also, they do not spread until they are older than the plant shown, and I see a small one in the lower left of the pic.

Comment: I was just now looking at it...huh! The guy underneath looks like Japanese Spurge.  Mine would pop out late spring...maybe I've got the scale wrong?

Comment: What about Heleborus?

Comment: There are Rodgersia's with serrated margins and mine were small when just starting to come up in the spring. Wish I had my books with me...

Comment: @stormy I meant the single leaf you can see in the lower left. Also, rodgersia has a less even serration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a species of sanicle, *Sanicula sp.* but I'm not sure which one. There are four possible in this region.

Answer (score 2):

The species pictured here is some type of sanicle (*Sanicula sp.*), I am not sure which. The species of sancile in region are biennials. The most common is S. canadensis, which is also sometimes called "Canadian Black Snakeroot" although it is not in the same family as white snakeroot. *Sanicula* are in the carrot family, Apiaceae.

All Sanicula in Maryland are native. All tend to occur in moist forested habitats, and all look rather similar.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like new Hellebore leaves to me.

Comment: Please elaborate this a bit. Explain why you think it looks like a Hellebore. Thanks!

Comment: The very start of the question reads "It is not evergreen", which rules out Hellebores, no?

Comment: A good point @NiallC., definitely not Hellebores.